# Unlinked exchanges when importing ecoinvent 3.8 ecospold 2

Tags: python, brightway

When I try to import ecoinvent 3.8 in the ecosplod_02 format I get:

19565 datasets
629959 exchanges
1655 unlinked exchanges
Type biosphere: 15 unique unlinked exchanges

which is a bit odd as it worked with the same files 3 weeks ago. When importing ecoinvent 3.9 there are no problems.

I have found an open issue for this on github (https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/issues/151) but sadly there are no workarounds yet. Until now I have tried using different versions of bw2, bw2io... as well as creating a fresh env but sadly nothing worked so far.

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the readme of the package: https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io

For importing ecoinvent 3.8 in a brightway2.5 project, you need bw2io 0.9.dev11.

`pip install bw2io==0.9.dev11`

And you have to use this version as well to setup your project before importing ecoinvent 3.8.

`bw2io.bw2setup()`